# Folder displaying in terminal but not finder

Tags: terminal, finder, webserver

Alright, so I just started beginning web development using my mac. My localhost says "It works" and I read somewhere I need to add my code files etc in *Library/WebServer/Documents*.

However, inside my Library, I do not see any WebServer folder. I can only see WebKit.

But if I try to locate the folder with terminal, it exists right there inside /Library.

What mystery is this? Please help me out.

Comment: You're certain you're not confusing /Library with ~/Library ? Also, are you using Go.. from the Finder, which would demand the / in front of Library. btw, Webkit is in ~/Lib, WebServer is in /Lib which would reinforce my first question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default location for WebServer documents is `/Library/WebServer/Documents`, which is inside the Library folder in the hard disk's root. The WebKit folder you see is at `~/Library/`, i.e. the current user's personal Library folder. That folder is hidden by default (if you go to the Home folder, `~`, in Finder, by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>, you'll either not see the Library folder at all, or it is slightly transparent).

In Finder, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> and enter `/Library/WebServer/Documents` and you'll be where you need to be.

Comment: For more then the last few major releases of OS X/macOS, in one's Home folder in Finder, the Library folder is hidden by default and if the defaults are still in play then you need to press the option key to see the Library folder on the Go menu in Finder.

Answer (score 5):

Mac OS has hidden folders within the depths of its hard drive. If you want to make these appear, you have to use the terminal.

1. Open the terminal.
2. Type the command `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE`, then press Enter (Or Return)
3. Type the command `killall Finder` (make sure you do the capital F) and press Enter/Return.

If you ever want to turn this off, just repeat the commands above, substituting `TRUE` for `FALSE`.

Answer (score -1):

The default storage location for web server documents is `/Library/WebServer/Documents`. You can open this directory without any problems if you enter this code in the terminal. You will then be taken straight to the directory.

`open /Library/WebServer/Documents`